# purrr pmap function arguments

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr, pmap

Functional programming with either `*apply` or `purrr` is my bread and butter yet I do not understand how `pmap` handles function arguments.

1. I can use their corresponding **variable names** (given a data frame as input) and do not have to worry about the order.
2. I can be more specific and use them as **named arguments**
3. I can use **similar** argument names
4. Yet I **cannot** use completely different names.

I've been looking through multiple similar questions yet fell short to find the appropriate answer to

A) what is going on and

B) how can I use arbitrary function argument names?

```
# dummy data -----------------------------------------------------------------
(iter_tibble <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:2,
                               b = 3:4,
                               c = 7:6))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     3     7
#> 2     2     4     6

# pmap it --------------------------------------------------------------------
# standard way
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, function(a, b, c) {
  paste(a, b, c)
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1 3 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2 4 6"

# switch order
# works and a maps to a, b to b etc
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, function(b, c, a) {
  paste(a, b, c)
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1 3 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2 4 6"

# name arguments
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, function(a1 = a, b1 = b, c1 = c) {
  paste(a1, b1, c1)
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1 3 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2 4 6"

# name arguments and switch order
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, function(b1 = b, c1 = c, asterix = a) {
  paste(b1, asterix, c1)
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "3 1 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "4 2 6"

# but when using a different initial letter
# ERROR
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, 
            purrr::safely(  
              function(b1 = b, c1 = c, obelix = a) {
                paste(b1, obelix, c1)
              }
            ))[1]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$result
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[1]]$error
#> <simpleError in .f(...): unused argument (a = 1)>
```

This behavior is rather different from how arguments can be called in regular R functions where abbreviations are possible (yet bad practice) but extensions are not possible.

```
# regular function usage -----------------------------------------------------
# abbrevate arguments - no problem
sample(1:4, s = 5, repla = TRUE)
#> [1] 1 3 4 3 1

# extend arguments? nope
sample(1:4, size = 5, replaceeeee = TRUE)
#> Error in sample(1:4, size = 5, replaceeeee = TRUE): unused argument (replaceeeee = TRUE)
```

My guess Is that the answer is rather about the `pmap` call to C than what happens in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misunderstanding here is that your 3rd and 4th options do not have "named arguments" but default argument values. You are supplying a function definition to the `.f` argument of `pmap`, not a function call.

`pmap` is doing partial argument matching the same way that base R does. It may make this clearer to turn on `options(warnPartialMatchArgs = TRUE)`. Here I'll take your 3rd example, factoring the function definition out to make it clearer what is happening:

```r
iter_tibble <- tibble::tibble(
  a = 1:2,
  b = 3:4,
  c = 7:6
)

f3 <- function(a1 = a, b1 = b, c1 = c) {
  paste(a1, b1, c1)
}

purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, f3)
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'a' to 'a1'
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'b' to 'b1'
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'c' to 'c1'
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'a' to 'a1'
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'b' to 'b1'
#> Warning in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#> partial argument match of 'c' to 'c1'
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1 3 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2 4 6"
```

This is exactly the same as the case with regular R functions that you describe, where supplied named arguments can be abbreviations of the function arguments. To put it another way, for the first row of the table, `pmap` basically constructs the call `f3(a = 1, b = 3, c = 7)`. `a`, `b`, and `c` come from the column names, the values come from the row.

When trying to evaluate this call, we see that the function `f3` does not have an argument `a`, but it has an argument `a1`. So the *named argument* `a = 1` in the *call* is partially matched to `a1` in the *function definition*. That's what the partial match warnings describe in the output. No "extensions" are happening. The fact that the argument `a1` has a default value of `a` is totally irrelevant here.

If you want to call a function and pass values in the tibble to differently named arguments, use a wrapper around it to change the interface. You can do this with a separate named function or (as is very common) using the `~` anonymous function syntax. Using your 5th example:

```r
iter_tibble <- tibble::tibble(
  a = 1:2,
  b = 3:4,
  c = 7:6
)

f5 <- function(b1, obelix, c1) {
  paste(b1, obelix, c1)
}

f5_wrapper <- function(a, b, c) {
  f5(b1 = b, obelix = a, c1 = c)
}

purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, f5_wrapper)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "3 1 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "4 2 6"
purrr::pmap(iter_tibble, ~ f5(b1 = ..2, obelix = ..1, c1 = ..3))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "3 1 7"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "4 2 6"
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes a lot of sense! Of course, it is rather about default arguments and partial matching than setting the arguments since `function` defines a function but does not call it. I guess I'd rather go with the wrapper function then since - personally - the `..1, ..2` notation is not explicit enough. Additionally, it can become confusing when providing many arguments this way.